# Godot keeps reimporting my deleted gd scripts, how can I stop this?

Tags: godot

I had a scene called WaterBody.tscn and I attached a script to it, I realized I didn't need WaterBody.tscn and I deleted it and its script. It still tries to reimport it, even though its gone.

I tried to recreate WaterBody.tscn and attach then remove the script, but when I delete WaterBody.tscn with it's script, it still tries to reimport!

Comment: Which version of Godot is this? Addendum: you can edit your question to add details. Follow up: Did you give the script a class name?

Comment: I tried to replicate the problem in Godot 3.5 and in Godot 4, but could not.

Comment: Hi, I also tested this and cannot reproduce. Can you expand on what you mean by "reimport"?

Comment: no clue what's going on but maybe a shot in the dark would be to delete `.import` files in the system files?